# Deep Learning Uncertainty Quantification

Tags: probability-theory

I am reading a paper about the quantification of uncertainty in Deep Learning models implemented through Shannon Entropy formula. The paper derives that, in Bayesian Neural Networks the entropy Shannon Entropy is always higher compared in deterministic models and theoretically justifies that recalling the Jensen inequality.

In a scenario of binary classification, the paper states:

$$SoftMax(u) = (1 + exp(-u))^-1

The softmax function is concave for u belonging to R+ and convex for R_. Therefore by Jensen's inequality:

$$SoftMax(E[u|\theta]) >= E_\theta[SoftMax(u|\theta)], if   u|\theta \in R+
$$SoftMax(E[u|\theta]) <= E_\theta[SoftMax(u|\theta)], if   u|\theta \in R-

This implies H(p^(D)) <= H(p^(B)) for all u belonging to R. Equality is obtained when p^(D) = p^(B) = 0.5

where p^(D) = Softmax(E[u|\theta]) and p^(B) = E_\theta[Softmax(u|\theta)].

What I don't understand is: given that H(x) calculates the Shannon entropy why is it valid also for then the function is concave and not only when it is convex ?

Comment: I've done some corrections about MathJax formatting. Please also correct the name of the function, as LaTeX doesn't like function names with more than one letter :-)